# Program starts with Windows even though it is not listed in autostart

Tags: windows-10, autorun, autostart

I installed the vpn service from [hide.me](https://hide.me) a couple of days ago. I noticed that it is starting with Windows every time so I removed it from autostart in the task-manager and restarted the computer to apply the settings.

However, it is still starting with Windows.

Why on earth is this happening and how can I stop it?

Comment: @Mokubai, thank you very much! There was a shortcut in `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` which caused the autostart

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From comments below it appears that hide.me regularly checks whether its start-up entry had been deleted and the program will recreate it if it is missing.  In this case you need go into the settings for the application and disable it.

> there is "start this app automatically with windows" setting and it was on

---

[Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) from Microsoft Sysinternals  can show you almost every start-up location in Windows and can disable items for you.

There may well be a start-up link or registry entry hiding somewhere that can be deactivated.

---

From Blacks comment above:

> There was a shortcut in
>
> ```
> C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
> ```
>
> which caused the autostart

Comment: Odd. Can you check if there is a service for it? Under the "service" tab in autoruns... If there is then set it to "manual" rather than disabling it.

Comment: Ah. Otherwise if you had it open when you closed Windows it may try to be helpful and re-run it when you start Windows again...

Comment: There are just so many places from where a program could autostart.

Comment: It seems like hide.me recreates the shortcut all the time somehow. I just deleted it and after the second restart it automatically started again and there is a new shortcut in autostart.

Comment: @Black I'd be really suspicious of that behavior and get a different VPN service.

Comment: @Black anything in the settings for that VPN app?

Comment: I just checked it, there is "start this app automatically with windows" setting and it was on, I think this will solve the issue.

Comment: @Black There might be something like a scheduled task that recreates the shortcut if it's missing. But disabling the startup from within the app's settings should solve the problem.