# How to change / set programs @ startup

Tags: windows-10, boot, autostart

A while back I was trying to setup a program to start at startup / boot.  I got the right executable to run but I don't know where that executable is.

I could not find the startup folder (and since I am using Windows 10 Enterprise Edition I don't believe there is one).
I also checked the registry. However there are no new files under Windows/CurrentVersion/Run.

Not sure where else I can look?

Comment: With 64/32bit virtualization, there are other places to check.  Are you able to run this? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Program starts with Windows even though it is not listed in autostart](https://superuser.com/questions/1278089/program-starts-with-windows-even-though-it-is-not-listed-in-autostart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The startup folder on Windows 10 is located at:

C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

(change your username here)

To directly access this folder, open Run, type shell:startup and hit Enter.

The location for ALL users is:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp

Yo open It directly you can you can press WinKey, type shell:common startup and hit Enter.